# Laravel resource converting my associative array into a standard array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-resource

PHP 7.4.16 & Laravel 8.61

I have the following code in my `Resource`:

```
   $arr = ['id' => $this->id, 'associations' => (object)[]];
   foreach ($tas as $ta) {
       $ta_id = $ta->id;
       $arr['associations']->$ta_id = ['suppliers' => [], 'offices' => []];
   }
   return $arr;
```

Where `$ta->id` is a integer.

When I print the `Resource::collection` of an item, I can see the `associations` with the right id as key being printed.

```
0:
-> associations:
--> 2:
---> ['suppliers' => [], 'offices' => []]
```

However, when I print a single resource (`new Resource(item)`), the `associations` array becomes a standard array.

```
associations:
-> 0:
--> ['suppliers' => [], 'offices' => []]
```

Why is this happening? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Didn't you ask this not long ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add `->toArray(null)` to your resource like this example that i tried before

```
BookingResource::collection($timeSlots)->toArray(null);
```

Comment: This does actually work, but why? My problem was that it was working for the collection but not for the single resource, doing `(new BookingResource($timeSlot))->toArray(null);` worked for me

Comment: When you pass `null` it remove the outer array for your to have an easy access to your objects